# Handle static content (css) in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application using Spring-MVC4
I configure my DispatcherServlet to handle all requests to '/'as below (web.xml) :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebAppConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.xxx.config
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebAppConfig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my directory structure that looks like the following picture :
[project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2estL.png)

and my jsp file is as below :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="/resources/css/Style.css"  media="screen"  />
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
    <c:import url="/resources/common/menu.jsp" />
    <h1>Home/Welcome page update</h1>
    <p>
        ${message}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally my webapp configuration is :

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(value = { "com.xxx" })
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")
    public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

        }

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }
 }
```

when i send my http request to the server, i can load jsp file in the / resources/common/menu.jsp but i can't handle css file ! 
when i send an http request to get css file like this http://localhost:8080/resources/css/Style.css i get 404 - Not Found error
Is there solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the probleme is in the jsp file when i call the css file with

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="/resources/css/Style.css"  media="screen"  />
```

the correct href is : `href="<c:url value='/resources/css/Style.css' />"`